# NextAuth js - cookies on return

Tags: next.js, next-auth

After closing my Next js application and then loading it back and navigating to the login page. In my Cookies (in browser application) I can see a `next-auth.session-token` and `next-auth.callback-url`, how do I retrieve this and check this session-token and then automatically redirect a user to the authenticated landing page / dashboard page?